# Reading data from main class

Tags: java, file-io

I  am writing a simple two-file project. I would like to know why the second file cannot read and print data from the main class. I know it can happen the other way around. Please clarify this for me. T

**Test.java**

```
package testme;

public class Test {   
     int a = 7;    

     public int getA() { return a; }

     public static void main( String args[] ) { 
         Test test = new Test();
     }     
}
```

**Testit.java**

```
package testme;

public class Testit {    
    Test t;    
    Testit() {
       t = new Test(); 
       System.out.println( t.getA() );
    }   
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting from this code? And why are you using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to create an instance of non-GUI class?

Comment: Did you want to create Testit in main instead of test?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
Test test = new Test();
```

with

```
Testit test = new Testit();
```

Comment: Sorry guys, I have corrected the code I entered.  TGM, your suggestion worked. Thank you.

Comment: Now, if I am building a gui using the first file with the main class, how would I handle reading data from this class to another one?

Comment: @user2143292 Pass data in a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your class definitions seem to be ok. Only problem is your main never starts up an instance of Testit.

Testit is successfully doing t = new Test();. So it now has access to the getA() method.

The same is not true the other way around. your main creates test = new Test(), but no reference to a TestIt Object.

try putting this in your main

```
Testit test = new Testit();
```

you should see a prinout of A (7)